# copy to clipboard for each list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, clipboard

i've got two list black and white numbers in JS Vue
for each one i made a button when i click on it the related numbers of list copy to clipboard
but only my white list copy to clipboard...any idea?

```
const copyClipBoard = (isWhite) => {
  let params;
  if (isWhite) params = selectedFiltersWhite.filters;
  else params = selectedFiltersBlack.filters;
  const data = { filter: { filters: params } };
  const token = settings.get("token");
  const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VUE_APP_SERVER;
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: baseUrl + `api/v1/user/check-blacklist/`,
    params: data,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }
  }).then((res) => {
      const array: any = [];
      res.data.data.items.forEach((el: any) => {
        array.push(el.number);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(array);
      });
      message.success("copeid");
    }).catch(error => {
      message.error("something went worng");
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: there are multiple places where things might go wrong, but you must add console.logs and debug it yourself.  is `isWhite` the correct value? is `selectedFiltersBlack.filters` returning what you expect?  does `res` contain the correct data?  only you can figure this out since we don't have knowledge of any of these values.  nothing is syntactically incorrect so there must be some logic error.

Comment: all value are correct .
actually i found it .
in my button in onclick event i should defined the `isWhite` type 
like this : `@click="copyToClipBoard(true)" ` for white list and 
`@click='copyToClipBoard(false)" ` for black list 

and you right...when i log it i figure out problems!